# Cocoa Data Abstraction Xcode 4

Tags: cocoa, xcode4

What is the best way to abstract out data access within a Mac/iPhone application using sqlite and Xcode 4?

I am traditionally a .NET/SQL Server developer so set about creating what was familiar to myself which was to:

- Created a xCode Workspace and added 
  in two projects.
- The first project 
  was my Mac OS X Cocoa Application.
- The second was a  Cocoa Library
  which    will hold all the common
  data access    logic (a bit like a
  Data Access    Layer).

However I cannot seem to find best practice on this issue as a lot of the examples on the web have all the data access logic within classes in the app.
I would like to separate my data access code so that it abstracts awy my data access in my Mac application and has the ability to be used by other projects in the workspace if required.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). It's built into OS X and iOS and handles pretty much all of your data management, from automatic undo support to building a SQLite model of your data and saving it.

Comment: I did not want to go down the CoreData route as its not really a true ORM and the fact the Apple don't use it in many of its apps doesn't fill me with great confidence. I wanted to go down the DAL route as I thought I can share this with both my Mac and iPad applications adhering more to the DRY principle. Thanks again though as your comment is still a valid one which people may find useful when looking at this question.

Comment: After much deliberation and testing I have decided to go down the CoreData route as its highly optimized and reduced the amount of code I had to write ten fold.